# Minted. Code highlighting right margin

Tags: margins, minted

I use minted for Python code, but with the long lines, instead of adapting to the document text width, it expands to the right without any kind of margin, and the code that doesn't fit, just does not appear.

I wouldn't like to write a linebreak for every long line because that would be a tedious task, I want all the code wrapped by minted to follow a margin.

How to work this out¿? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Version 2 of `minted` has the `breaklines` option.

Comment: Thank you! You mean, it is necessary to use a breakline always¿? Not a field like "Text width" or something like that for the whole code¿?

Comment: The problem is that the document geometry, doesn't apply to the code wrapped in the minted tag, so the margins are different, I have tried it:
`\begin{minted}
[breaklines=true]` and it makes the code not to drift away, but It doesn't apply the margin, I need something like this: 

`\begin{minted}
[breaklines=true,margins=5cm] `
But it doesn't seem to exist, does it¿?

Comment: Can you please add a small compilable example?

Comment: `minted` uses `fancyvrb` internally, so `fancyvrb`'s options `xleftmargin`, `xrightmargin`, and `resetmargins` are available for working with margins.